# perl regex to match "==" at end of line

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having trouble getting this perl statement to properly filter an output file.

```
perl -00 -wnl -e '
   /Instance list size <\d+>\n(.+)\*\*end/s or die "error msg\n";
foreach my $line (split("\n", $1)) {
  $line =~ /(==)$/ && print "\"$_\"" ;
}' $Output_File 2>&1
```

The output I'm interested is all lines terminated with ==. But for some reason, when I run this, even in a file with only 8 lines and 1 intended match, I'm getting 22 matches.

Comment: sample input, output?

Comment: Why are you splitting on newline when -n loops over the input?

Comment: be advised that if you are trying to validate a base64 encoded string, even if it will usually end in `==`, it can end in just one `=` or even none.

Comment: thanks @kaᵠ. In this situation, the binary data length is constant, and it will always end in ==.

Comment: @squiguy, Look up -00

Comment: @ikegami Isn't that "slurp" mode? There are so many conflicting flags given.

Comment: @squiguy, Paragraph mode (`$/='';`). -0777 is slurp (`$/=undef;`).

Comment: Please provide a complete demonstration of your problem. Your code doesn't do anything at all without data, much less what you said it does.

Comment: You could try changing `split ..., $1` to `split ..., "$1"`, but I doubt it'll make a difference.

Comment: @squiguy, None of the flags are conflicting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using the `-n` option and still have a `foreach my $line ...` in your script. The whole point of `-n` is that it will feed your script one line at a time automatically.

Here's something that works for me:

```
$ cat foo.txt
asdfasdfsadf asdf a== asfd a sdf
aasdf asdf asd f==

asdf asdf asdf sad fsdaf==
asdfasdfasdf sadfsadf=aa sdfasdf =

$ perl -ne "print if /==$/" < foo.txt
aasdf asdf asd f==
asdf asdf asdf sad fsdaf==
```

Comment: This is working for me in isolation but not in the context of the test I'm running. I've simplified the script (which, for the record, I did not write but inherited) to remove the `foreach`, but when I use `print if /==$/'`, I get 0 matches. If I remove the $ `print if /==/'`, I am back at 22 matches.

Comment: @trav1th, are you sure the `==`s in your file are at the end of the lines? It could be `foo == ` (a space after `==`), which would keep your regex from matching.

Comment: I double checked. There is no space. The newline gets chomped by -l, so it should match fine.

Comment: @trav1th: The fact that you are getting 22 matches for a file with 8 lines is rather strange. Could you post a  hex dump of this 8-line file, perhaps via `hexdump -C` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could always try `grep`: `grep '==$' file.txt`